# Clarification on the Lid-Driven Cavity Problem in CFD

Tags: numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

I need some clarifications on The Lid-Driven Cavity Problem.

What does it actually mean? I know cavities are bubbles created when a fluid moves through liquid in low pressure zones, but what does the lid-driven cavity actually mean in context? Are we saying we take the bubbles to be of a square cavity? And also, that the lid is the upper part of the square, where the other three sides are no-slip conditions, correct?

I also need more clarifications on:

initial conditions

boundary conditions

free slip and no-slip boundary conditions

and how to non-dimensionalize the Navier-Stokes equations.

Comment: Wikipédia has a great article about the non-dimensionalization of NS equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-dimensionalization_and_scaling_of_the_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations

Comment: Also I believe most of your questions belong in MS Physics and not really in MS Mathematics

Comment: Asked and answered on [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461782/clarification-on-the-lid-driven-cavity-problem-in-cfd)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with bubbles. You have a viscous fluid inside a container, which is set into motion by moving the top lid with a certain velocity. It is a good test for numerical solvers because of the low velocity recirculation areas that appear close to the bottom corners.